# how to know time spent of post requests when sending file from client to server?

Tags: python, python-requests

I just learned about http, and I got this task to get the time spent when sending data from client to server. And this is my code:

```
import requests
import glob
import time
import base64

url = 'http://0.0.0.0:5000'
path = './10_mb'
folder = [f for f in glob.glob(path + '**/*', recursive = True)]

def load_data():

    for image in glob.glob('*.jpg'):
    with open(image, 'rb') as imageFile:
         image_s = {'file_image':open(image, 'rb')}

    return image_s

def send_data():

    start = time.time()
    r = requests.post(url, files = load_data())
    end = time.time()

    print('client 1 : {} ms'.format((end-start)*1000))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    send_data()
```

In the code I put `time.time()` to get the time spent when sending the data to server. I have a doubt, I assumed with my code I get the time spent from the process of sending data from client to server and back to the client, not just from client to the server.

Is that a right thing to do or to get time just from client to server? if not how to do it? thanks in advance!

Comment: This works to time the call, what is wrong?

Comment: Note that you are also timing the call to `load_data`, which times a `for` loop, finding all of the `jpeg` files with `glob`, and opening those files. This could muddy the results of your timing

Comment: i have a doubt at the workflow of `post` function. does the `post` send data from client to server? or from client to server and back to the client ? @JBirdVegas

Comment: maybe if you use `socket` and write all from scratch then you would measure this time. Or maybe if you get requests' source code, dig in code and change it then you could get this value. Both would need a lot of work.